# What is the meaning of putting a word in parentheses at the end of a statement [Internet Speech]?

Tags: internet-slang, casual

I'm sorry, I can't think of a better way to title this question, but I took a screenshot of the short Twitter exchange showing what I mean:

[image]

In case anything goes wrong with the image, here it is in text:

Person 1: 一般って何なんでしょうね……（哲学）

Person 2: 疑問になる時点で一般的ではないのかもしれないですね…（真理）

I've seen this many times in written form on Twitter and other forums, and I finally thought to ask about it. I think I have a vague idea of it being sort of a way to put a statement into a particular frame or context? Like Person 1 is trying to be a bit funny by suggesting that this is a philosophical musing, and Person 2 is playing along by framing their response as "Truth".

Am I somewhat close? It feels a bit like a "meme" to me, and I'm not sure quite how I should interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation of it as "sort of a way to put a statement into a particular frame or context" sounds adequate.

As for "It feels a bit like a "meme" to me", it is possible that such a usage became widespread on the internet partly due to [真夏｛まなつ｝の夜｛よる｝の淫夢｛いんむ｝, a gay porn series that has led to many memes](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/a-midsummer-nights-lewd-dream-%E7%9C%9F%E5%A4%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%9C%E3%81%AE%E6%B7%AB%E5%A4%A2).

> また、淫夢語録を用いた文章では、文の最後に括弧書きで状況や感情の説明をする事が多いのも大きな特徴の1つ。代表例としては「（迫真）」「（棒読み）」「（困惑）」「（震え声）」「（小並感）」等が挙げられる。
>   なお、このような表現の仕方は淫夢ジャンルの登場以前にも少なからず存在しており、同時にこれらの表現は淫夢特有の物という訳では無いので注意されたし。
>   [https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/淫夢語録](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E6%B7%AB%E5%A4%A2%E8%AA%9E%E9%8C%B2)

That is, this "parenthesis talk" tends to be used in large quantities when using the memes from 真夏の夜の淫夢; however, it must be noted that such "parenthesis talk" has existed way before 淫夢 memes existed, and also that these expressions are not at all specific to 淫夢 memes.